# Jupyter notebook: The port is already in use, trying another port?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I can join the port sucessfully by 
`ssh -N -L 8888:127.0.0.1:8888 server_ip`

But if I just join the server, and then use `jupyter notebook`, I can't open the port sucessfully.

```
ssh server_ip
jupyter notebook --port=8888
```

`Error:`

```
The port 8888 is already in use, trying another port.
```

What is the reason and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check which application is currently running on port 8888 by following commands on Linux machine. If in case it happens to be an existing jupyter, you may try killing that process and start a new one.

Check current process running in 8888

```
lsof -i:8888
```

To kill the current process.

```
kill $(lsof -t -i:8888)
```

To forcefully kill the current process

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8888)
```

If for some reason you wish not to kill the current process, you may try launching jupyter on a different port.

```
jupyter notebook --port=8889
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have some other process on port 8888.

You can either:

1) Kill the process on port 8888 and then launch jupyter-notebook on port 8888

2) Launch jupyter notebook on a different port and then use ssh to connect to the new port